# Error "Database does not support creation of triggers" when installing CiviCRM 5.33.0 on Wordpress 6.2

Tags: wordpress, error, installation, trigger

We are trying to install CiviCRM 5.33.0 (not the latest because of an SQL error that we previously got) on Wordpress 6.2 and keep getting the error "Database does not support creation of triggers". We think that it could be a database access or with the web host issues but not at all convinced about it.

Any help?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to ask your hosting provider if the account supports database triggers. Sometimes it doesn't with shared hosting. See also https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/requirements/#mysql-configuration

Comment: Alright done we will see what they say. Thanks for your quick answer !